# Matlab: fmincon, Portfolio Optimization, difficulties with free variables

Tags: matlab, optimization, portfolio

i´m trying to replicate a paper ("Is the marketporfolio mean-variance efficient after all?" from Levy & Roll) in Matlab. I want to **minimize** the following function (D) with its constraints:

[Objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inrrw.png)

[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3OsF.png)

I want to get **mu** and **sigma**,

furthermore alpha, q and r_z are free variables, where

- **alpha**: 0 ≤ α ≤ 1 is a parameter determining
  the relative weight assigned to deviations of the means relative to deviations
  of the standard deviations.
- **q**: q > 0 is the constant of proportionality
- **r_z** : zero beta rate (risk free interest rate)

I have:

- **mu^sam:** Vector of means of historical returns
- **sigma^sam**: Vector of standard deviation of historical returns
- **Covariance matrix**
- weights **x_m,i**

Now i don´t know how to handle the free variables alpha, q and r_z

My objective function D :

```
function dist=distOpt(alpha, N, x0, mu_sam, sigma_sam)

sumSigma=0; 

for i=1:N 
       sumMu=sumMu+((x0(i)-mu_sam(i))/sigma_sam(i))^2; 
       sumSigma=sumSigma+((x0(N+i)-sigma_sam(i))/sigma_sam(i))^2; 
end
dist=sqrt(alpha*(1/N)*sumMu + (1-alpha)*(1/N)*sumSigma);
```

And constraints:

```
Mu_sam=repelem(-0.0001,y-1);
 Sigma_sam=repelem(-0.0002,y-1);     
 x0=[Mu_sam Sigma_sam];

function [c,ceq] = confuneq(x0,rz,Cor,Weights)
q=1;

ceq=diag(x0(7:end))*Cor*diag(x0(7:end))*Weights' - q*(x0(1:6)'-rz);
c=[];
```

My use of fmincon:

```
optFunc=@(x0) distOpt(alpha,(y-1),x0, Mu_sam, Sig_sam); 
 options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','MaxFunctionEvaluations', 12000,'FunValCheck','on');
 nonlcon=@(c,ceq) confuneq(x0,r_z, rho, Weights);
 [x0, fval, exitFlag]= fmincon(optFunc,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlcon,options);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: In optimization-theory, *free-variables* are usually the ones without bounds (-inf, inf). Of your 3 example-vars at least 2 are bounded = non-free.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i don´t know how to handle the free variables alpha, q and r_z

I think you have two options:

1) Choose fix values for them.

2) Include them into your x to get optimal values.